# Identifying the Telegram-Bot-Owner not possible?

Tags: telegram-bot

I am currently implementing a telegram bot that needs to differentiate between the one that owns the bot - meaning the one who has been provided with the bots credentials - and all other users chatting with the bot.

I am using webhooks and from what I can see, there is no parameter provided in the message object, that I could use to identify this relationship. Parameter like surname, lastname are not sufficient as they are ambiguous and the @username is not provided at all.

One could use the chat-id, but I cannot see any API Call that would offer userData ..

Any ideas ?

BR Andre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using python, save your (admin) `chat.id` to a config file, then compare it via `chat.id` from incoming message entity.

Comment: Thank you Alen - I think I understand what you mean. But I do not see how this would help in my scenario. Being the admin, where could I get the chat.id in order to store it into a config file? The only way doing this would be starting the bot in the messenger  and observe the webhook update call in the code, right? This is nothing that non-technicians can do...

Comment: Maybe additionally a few words to explain the background. I have customers asking to implement a bot for them. But basically they want to stay enabled to configure the bot basics, like profile, picture, description themselves with botfather. In order to enable me to implement some custom funtionality I need to get the bot credentials, but also the admins user-id/chat.id ..

Comment: you can get information like `user.id` using the library, I currently don't know python-telegram-bot API, but i do know another 3rd party library called Pyrogram which has a method `get_users` [refer](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_users#pyrogram.Client.get_users) passing user.id or username as parameter to the function will return public information about a specific user.

Comment: right, but like I said, I need an ident that is available for the user that is owner of the bot account. What I found out in the meantime is, that the only ident available is the user public account - like  @abc4711. As soon you provide this to the public you will see it at the bot-API.

Comment: Soory I don't understand what you said, Is it identity? if yes u can identify owner using both username and user id

Comment: the key of it is to use the public userName to identify the bot-owner, Which is optional and needs to be defined by the account owner ..